# Наибольший из повторяющихся элементов данного массива

Tags: массивы, c++

Найти наибольший из повторяющихся элементов данного массива. Нужно на с++

Comment: @Puniisher943, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Решение - в лоб:

1. Отсортировать массив с помощью `std:sort` в порядке убывания.
2. Последовательно просматривать элементы массива, начиная с наибольшего.
3. Первое найденное неуникальное значение (равное предыдущему) - искомая величина.

Comment: спасибо, попробую